# How to obtain visible borders of canvas placed on scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, scroll

I have canvas which is placed on scrollviewer in order to allow scrolling. Is it possible to get coordinates of visible part of canvas?

I was trying to calculate it that way

```
leftBorder = ScrollViewer1.HorizontalOffset;
rightBorder = ScrollViewer1.ViewportWidth - ScrollViewer1.HorizontalOffset;

topBorder = ScrollViewer1.VerticalOffset;
bottomBorder = ScrollViewer1.ViewportHeight - ScrollViewer1.VerticalOffset;
```

but it seems that it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The Horizontal and Vertical offset is the actual scroll value in that direction. 
Besides that, if you want the size of the content without any scrollbars that might be visible.
You can search for the child named "PART_ScrollContentPresenter". This shows the actual content of the scrollviewer, and this content will be resized when the scrollbars needs more space.

Hope that helps.